# "Partial" Levy Collapse mantaining $\kappa$ inaccessible. (Solovay model.)

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm trying to fill in the details to a line in a proof in Kanamori's exposition of Solovay's theorem on Lebesgue Measurability. I include the pertient information: [image]

My question is on "$\kappa$ is still inaccessible in $V[a]$ by 10.12 and 10.17(e)."

By these lemmas I know that $\kappa$ is still inaccessible in some $V[G\cap Col(\lambda,\delta)]$ that contains $V[a]$ (for this I'm assuming $|Col(\lambda,\delta)|<\kappa$ which I haven't actually checked) but I feel like I need $V[a]$ to be actually equal to some extension of this form to get $\kappa$ to be inaccessible. Sorry if this is a silly question I've been feeling very confused for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being inaccessible is *downwards absolute*: if $W_1$ is an *end extension* of $W_0$ (that is, $W_0\subseteq W_1$ and for every $a\in W_0$, $\{b\in W_1: W_1\models b\in a\}=\{b\in W_0: W_0\models b\in a\}$ -  e.g. forcing extensions are end extensions, $V$ is an end extension of $L$, etc.), then every inaccessible cardinal in $W_1$ is an inaccessible cardinal in $W_0$. For example, any inaccessible cardinal in $V$ is also inaccessible in $L$.

Why? Well, first let's show that every cardinal of $W_1$ is a cardinal of $W_0$. Suppose $W_0$ thinks $\alpha$ isn't a cardinal. Then $W_0$ contains some $f$ which is a bijection between $\alpha$ and some ordinal $\beta<\alpha$. But then $f\in W_1$, since $W_0\subseteq W_1$; and so $W_1$ also sees that $\alpha$ isn't a cardinal.

The same reasoning carries us through inaccessibility. For $\lambda<\kappa$, $W_1$ thinks there is no surjection from $2^\lambda$ to $\kappa$; since $W_1\supseteq W_0$, we have $(2^\lambda)^{W_0}\subseteq (2^\lambda)^{W_1}$, and so $W_0$ thinks there is no surjection from $2^\lambda$ to $\kappa$ either. Similarly, if $f: \alpha\rightarrow\kappa$ is in $W_0$, then $f$ is in $W_1$ as well, so any witness to $\kappa$ being singular in $W_0$ lifts to a witness to $\kappa$ being singular in $W_1$. (E.g., it is impossible to force a singular cardinal to be regular, although the opposite is easy.)

Lots of large cardinal properties are downwards absolute in this way - specifically, the ones which are $\Pi_1$. However, there are also plenty which aren't; a trivial example being *measurable* cardinals, since there are no measurables in $L$.

---

Of course, the *converse* fails: an ordinal $\kappa\in W_1$ may seem "large" in $W_0$, while $W_1$ sees that it is actually quite small (e.g. countable). For example, if there is a measurable cardinal in $V$, the $\omega_1^L$ is countable; indeed, there are countable (in $V$) ordinals which $L$ thinks are inaccessible, Mahlo, weakly compact, . . .

Comment: I thought of this and tried to prove it but got a bit tangled up. Could you outline a proof for me? Thank you. (Cause even if they have the same ordinals they may disagree very strongly on which are cardinals and which aren't.)

Comment: @Mingus See my edit. Basically, the point is that any *counterexample* (to being a cardinal, or being a strong limit, or being regular) in the small model lifts to the large model.

Comment: In particular, they'll only disagree *in one direction*: the bigger model will have no *more* cardinals than the smaller one (in the sense that every non-cardinal in the small model is a non-cardinal in the big model too), and so on.

Comment: @Mingus Have my comments adequately addressed your question?

Comment: I haven't had time to carefully read through your answer so I haven't "accepted" it, but I will soon and I'm sure it will be adequate. Thank you.