# Proof of Solovay's theorem

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm reading, on Jech's book *Set Theory, 3rd millenium edition*, the proof of Solovay's theorem for measurability of projective sets. The proof goes on using some properties of Boolean algebras.

In particular, let $M$ be the $\operatorname{ZFC}$-model $M[G]$, the generic extension carried out by the Lévy collapse $Col(\aleph_0,< \kappa)$, $\kappa \in M$ inaccessible, and $B$ the relating Boolean algebra. If $s\in M[G]$ is a countable sequence of ordinals of $M$, there exists a complete subalgebra $D\subseteq B$ such that $M[s]=M[D\cap G]$ (this happens every time i have a model between $M$ and $M[G]$, and this is the Lemma 15.43 of the book).

What I can't see (in the Lemma 26.16 in the proof of the theorem) are the following:

- *Since $B$ is $\kappa$-saturated, there exists a subalgebra $D\subseteq B$ such that $|D| < \kappa$, and $M[s]=M[D\cap G]$.*

and, immediately,

- *It follows that $\kappa$ is inaccessible in $M[s]$.*

I'd say these follow only by basic properties of Boolean algebras (and the construction of $D$ in Lemma 15.43) and by the definition of inaccessible cardinals, but I can't see why they hold.

Answer (score 2):

1. Fix a name $\dot s$ for $s$. Fix $\eta$ large enough such that
   $$
   \Vdash_B \dot s \subseteq \eta.
   $$
   For each $\alpha \in \eta$ let
   $$
   u_\alpha = \| \check{\alpha} \in \dot s \|.
   $$
   Since $B$ is $\kappa$-saturated there is a partition $W \subseteq \{ u_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \eta \}$ of size $< \kappa$. Let $D$ be the subalgebra of $B$ generated by $W$. Since $\kappa$ is regular, we have $|D | < \kappa$. By the proof of Corollary 15.42 it furthermore follows that
   $$
   M[s] = M[D \cap G].
   $$
2. Let $\delta = |D |$. $D$ has the $\delta < \kappa$-chain condition and therefore $\kappa$ remains a regular cardinal in $M[G \cap D]$. Furthermore, for $\lambda < \kappa$, there are at most
   $$
   (\delta^\delta)^\lambda < \kappa
   $$
   [nice $D$-names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_name) for subsets of $\lambda$. (I can't find the relevant notion in Jech's book but in Kunen's Set Theory book it's discussed on p.266.) Hence
   $$M[D \cap G] \models 2^{\lambda} < \kappa$$
   and $\kappa$ remains a strong limit in $M[D \cap G]$.

Comment: Surely we can construct W with Zorn's Lemma (a massimal antichain of B is an antichain that is massimal). But why the cardinality of D is less then k? Does it hold also for arbitrary k?

For the second point, I have no idea about what a nice name is (I'm new on this subject and I think this approach is very different from the boolean one, isn't it?). Is there another "boolean"-proof? I know that they are both related but I can't translate your proof...

Comment: Nice names in posets are nice names in Boolean algebras. So this is the "Boolean" proof - well, at least one of them. The cardinality of $W$ is less than $\kappa$ because $B$ has the $\kappa$-chain condition (in other words because $B$ is $\kappa$-saturated). If you now close $W$ to become a subalgebra, the cardinality will stay below $\kappa$ because $\kappa$ is of cofinality $> \aleph_0$. PS: Surely something equivalent to "nice names" is defined in Jech's book but I couldn't find it.

Comment: The complete subalgebra generated is included in the algebra generated, which has the same cardinality of the generator set, and this works every time that this set has cardinality greater or equal than $\alep_0$, or not? Anyway, thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Wait... does Jech actually mean 'complete subalgebra' when he writes 'subalgebra'? If that's the case, I guess you actually need that $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible...

Comment: The subalgebra constructed in Lemma 15.43 is complete, and we need this to ensure that M[s] is a generic extension. Where is the problem?

Comment: Morover, when I say "by definition of inaccessible cardinal", in the question, I mean an argument about "witness" like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032003/partial-levy-collapse-mantaining-kappa-inaccessible-solovay-model?rq=1 .  It seems the one I need...

Comment: You don't need completeness to ensure that something is a generic extension - any 'generic filter' over a Boolean algebra will do. And what I did to show that $\kappa$ remains inaccessible is to prove Proposition 10.12. But I don't know what 'witness' you refer to.